# NullPointerException using Map and different classes

Tags: java, dictionary, reference, hashmap, private

I have been trying to code a new class in JAVA where I use a Map and HashMap to relay information to different classes rather than declaring the Map locally in every class.

I have created a new class "GetRoom.java" which has 4 different methods:

- **void** addRoom(int id, Room room)
- **Room** byID(int id)
- **boolean** containsID(int id)
- **Room** doIexist()

The code is as follows:

```
private static Map<Integer, Room> hotelRooms = new HashMap<Integer, Room>();

public static void addRoom(int id, Room room){
    hotelRooms.put(id, room);
}

public static Room byID(int id){
    return hotelRooms.get(id);
}

public static Room doIexist(){
    return hotelRooms.get(5);
}

public static boolean containsID(int id){
    return hotelRooms.containsKey(id);
}
```

If I use the byID function in any other class it will return NullPointerException, whereas, if I use the doIexist function then it will return the Room ID 5. When calling hotelRooms.size() I can see that I have filled it with 42 rooms before but can not reference them outside of GetRoom.java

Any help is much appreciated!

**edit:**
This is where I call the code from:

```
public static void Compose(ServerHandler Client, User theUser, Environment Server) throws Exception
{
    User CurrentUser = Client.GetSession();
    int RoomId = CurrentUser.CurrentRoomId;
    Channel Socket = Client.Socket;
    Room R = GetRoom.byID(RoomId); // If I change this to GetRoom.doIExist(); it will work

    ServerMessage HeightMap = new ServerMessage(ServerEvents.HeightMap1);
    HeightMap.writeUTF(R.GetModel().getMap());
    HeightMap.Send(Socket);

    ServerMessage RelativeMap = new ServerMessage(ServerEvents.HeightMap2);
    String Map = R.GetModel().SerializeRelativeMap;
    RelativeMap.writeUTF(Map);
    RelativeMap.Send(Socket);       
}
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at messages.outgoing.rooms.LoadMapsMessageComposer.Compose(LoadMapsMessageComposer.java:30)
    at messages.incoming.rooms.LoadMapsMessageEvent.run(LoadMapsMessageEvent.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

LoadMapsMessageComposer.java:30 is the line that has

> HeightMap.writeUTF(R.GetModel().getMap());

Comment: We need to see the stack trace and the calling code. This looks fine, and I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I updated the post so that you can see where it is called from, I have been trying to do this all day and have no idea why it won't work.

Comment: And the stack trace. As a note, you seem to be using C# naming, and it will be confusing to any Java developer trying to read your code. In Java, convention is to use lowercase initial letters for member names (methods and variables). I suspect that your *actual* NPE is occurring at your `R.GetModel()` call, since `byID` will return `null` if there's no entry in the map for that key.

Comment: Yes, that is right. I have updated the post again and added in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while you may have several rooms added to your map, you *don't* have a room corresponding to the `currentRoomId`. That means that `get(id)` and thus `byID` are returning `null`, and then you try to call a method on that `null` value.

Comment: Thanks I had eventually figured this out, thanks for all of your help!